# window.top.location vs window.location

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, window.location

how to sync window.top.location and window.location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you set the parent of the frame (`top`) to the location of the frame document...

```
top.location = self.location;
```

Of course, this code must be executed within the iframe, and is succeptible to the [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

window.top.location  is return you to  broswer's address bar location  even you'r in i-frame or page..
window.location is return location of your current page address in case facebook apps. if you want to top query-string you have to use

`alert(window.top.location);`

if u want to replace top location then

`window.top.location = "http://whatever.com";`