# How can I redirect from inside an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, iframe, redirect, location-href

I use website redirect page `window.location.href` , its working fine on all traffic also on `iframe` traffic.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     window.location.href="http://newUrlLocation.com";           
 </script>
```

But when I use `top.location.href` it does not redirect from inside an `iframe`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    top.location.href="http://newUrlLocation.com";
</script>
```

Any one help me please, I want to use `top.location.href` for all my traffic also for `iframe`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3193193/298240

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect parent window from an iframe action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action)

Answer (score -1):

Use: `window.top.location.href`

instead of: `top.location.href`

Difference between the two: [window.top.location vs window.location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354561/window-top-location-vs-window-location)

Comment: jquery.js:9729 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: Do you have the rights to redirect the top frame? You can't just do this with every page.